# Value validation at compile/coding time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was using Amazon SDK and notice this "warning":

[image]

How is it possible? I did not install any plugin or extension, I just install AWS SDK through Nuget. Is it a standard C#/Visual Studio feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this is a feature that nuget packages can choose to leverage. These are sometimes called "code-aware libraries". They are nuget packages that ship with built-in roslyn analyzers. A discussion of how to write an analyzer is a some what extended topic. The magic is in the nuget's special [analyzers folder](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/analyzers-conventions):

> Analyzers themselves are typically packaged and distributed as part of the NuGet packages that implement the API or library in question.

Microsoft has published several examples and walkthroughs in various places:

- A [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt297717.aspx) for the immutable collections library.
- An example for a hypothetical RSS library is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt573715.aspx).